# react router returning to homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app built and at the end of the quiz I want a
simple link that leads back to the homepage...
I would assume that when you click the link on the last
page it renders just the homepage but it seems to be showing me a blank page...

This homepage has the route set up for `'/'` and should display the ParentComponent. but when i click the link to the `'/'` path (in my finalScore component) it just leads me to a blank page. does anyone know why?

homepage looks like this:

```js
import QFIB from './QFIB'
import AFIB from './AFIB'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Nav />
      <div class='qAndAContainer'>
    <Route path='/' exact component={ParentComponent} />
    <Route path='/StartTest' component={StartTest} />
     </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

and my last page looks like this: ***it consists right now of just a
simply link that says home which should take the user back to the homepage...
I already set up where the hompage should be rendered in my app file
so why is this giving me a blank page?**

```js
const FinalScore = ({score}) => {
  return (
     <Link to='/' exact>home</Link>
     <div/>
     </Switch>
     </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are using multiple Routers in your app. You should use one Router per app, that is all. You can have multiple Routes but just one single Router.

Comment: great stuff. thank you

Comment: If it solved your problem you can answer your own question and explain how you solve it. By the way, there is no `exact` prop for the `Link` component. I should suggest taking your time and reading React Router's [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).